# mysql query to match some record where column contains multiple comma separated values

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, join

I am working on a project.I have a table tblhomework which have a column students code-which contains students code separated by comma.Now I have few drop downs to search a record among which is search by student name.Now I have students code in my table how should I match it against the student name.I am using the following query,till now I am matching using students code but now I have to match by student name

Query

```
string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
SELECT 
tblhomework.ID,
tblteacher.TEACHERNAME,
tblclass.CLASSNAME,
tblhomework.Title,
tblhomework.HomeworkDetail,
tblhomework.StudentsCode 
FROM tblhomework 
join tblclass on tblclass.CLASSCODE=tblhomework.ClassCode 
join tblteacher on tblteacher.TSHORTNAME=tblhomework.Tshortcode 
where tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "';
```

Following is the screenshot of the result I am getting
[image]

I have a student table which contains student names of students which you can use.

Comment: May I suggest alternating your db structure and add many to many relationship table that maps students and teachers?

Comment: I can't change the db structure

Comment: please suggest some change in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FIND_IN_SET in your current SQL:-

```
SELECT 
    tblhomework.ID,
    tblteacher.TEACHERNAME,
    tblclass.CLASSNAME,
    tblhomework.Title,
    tblhomework.HomeworkDetail,
    tblhomework.StudentsCode 
FROM tblhomework 
JOIN tblclass ON tblclass.CLASSCODE=tblhomework.ClassCode 
JOIN tblteacher ON tblteacher.TSHORTNAME=tblhomework.Tshortcode 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('" + studentcode + "', tblhomework.StudentsCode);
```

However, not this will only work if there are no spaces before / after the commas in the list of student codes

To join that against the student names table (and making assumptions on the layout of that table) use something like this:-

```
SELECT 
    tblhomework.ID,
    tblteacher.TEACHERNAME,
    tblclass.CLASSNAME,
    tblhomework.Title,
    tblhomework.HomeworkDetail,
    tblhomework.StudentsCode ,
    tblstudent.StudentsName
FROM tblstudent 
JOIN tblhomework ON FIND_IN_SET(tblstudent.StudentsCode, tblhomework.StudentsCode);
JOIN tblclass ON tblclass.CLASSCODE=tblhomework.ClassCode 
JOIN tblteacher ON tblteacher.TSHORTNAME=tblhomework.Tshortcode 
WHERE tblstudent.StudentsCode = '" + studentcode + "'
```

Searching by student name (although generally it would be easier if the drop down returned the numeric unique student id):-

```
SELECT 
    tblhomework.ID,
    tblteacher.TEACHERNAME,
    tblclass.CLASSNAME,
    tblhomework.Title,
    tblhomework.HomeworkDetail,
    tblhomework.StudentsCode ,
    tblstudent.StudentsName
FROM tblstudent 
JOIN tblhomework ON FIND_IN_SET(tblstudent.StudentsCode, tblhomework.StudentsCode);
JOIN tblclass ON tblclass.CLASSCODE=tblhomework.ClassCode 
JOIN tblteacher ON tblteacher.TSHORTNAME=tblhomework.Tshortcode 
WHERE tblstudent.StudentsName = '" + studentname + "'
```

Comment: thanx it is working,what changes I have to do if instead of studentcodes in tblhomework in select I will have studentsname because currently i am getting only one student name(tblstudent.StudentsName)

Comment: There should only be a single student name returned (as it is specified) but could be mulitple rows for the homework, etc (eg, the student name with the code 10555 should bring back multiple rows). Can you update your question with the table declares (as text so they can be used in sql, not screen prints) and a bit of sample data, along with the output you require.

Answer (score 0):

To store comma separated values in column is bad design you should look at [**Database Normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and do normalize your structure by storing all related student codes in a junction table,but as from above comments you said you can't change structure so in mysql you can use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) and join your students table ,i am not familiar with c# syntax so i have posted mysql query,also use your original name convention for the columns

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
  h.ID,
  t.TEACHERNAME,
  c.CLASSNAME,
  h.Title,
  h.HomeworkDetail,
  h.StudentsCode 
FROM
  tblhomework h
  JOIN tblclass c
    ON c.CLASSCODE = h.ClassCode 
  JOIN tblteacher t
    ON t.TSHORTNAME = h.Tshortcode 
  JOIN students s ON(FIND_IN_SET(s.StudentsCode, h.StudentsCode) > 0)
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('studentcode', h.StudentsCode) > 0
OR s.student_name LIKE 'test'
```

Comment: @rupinder18 i have updated my answer also please post error details next time onwards

Comment: now the query is being executed without any error but I am getting all the rows of tblhomework,like instead of test i searched for 'shina rana' but I am not getting the desired result

Comment: @rupinder18 post some sample data with your table definitions at http://sqlfiddle.com/ and provide sql fiddle link back here

Comment: the above query provided by kickstart is working fine just need an additional field with student names instead of students code in select

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'FIND_IN_SET'` function to search in comma separated set of values.

Change your where clause as below:

```
where FIND_IN_SET( @student_code, tblhomework.studentscode );
```

Use `AddWithValue` to bind value of `'studentcode'` read from text box.

```
string studentcode = txt_studentcode.Text.ToString();
myCommand = new MySqlCommand( sql_query_string, connection );
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@student_code", studentcode );
```

And execute.

Comment: I know I can use find_in_set() with where clause but I have to do by using students name not by students code,how to do that

Comment: OK. It seems [kickstart has already posted a valid answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23887908/767881). You can try that.